# Unable to find the root cause of Inflate exception, possible fix?

Tags: java, android

The app force closes with the error :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxx.xxxx/com.xxx.xxx.activity.ExamActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #219: Error inflating class TextView

In order to resolve the issue, I tried solutions to the following questions:

- [Android app unable to start activity componentinfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900437/android-app-unable-to-start-activity-componentinfo)
- [java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898444/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-start-activity-componentinfo)

However, since none of the above solutions did work, I am opening another question.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong to cause the aforementioned error:

Here is the Activity layout resource file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F7F7F7"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".activity.ExamActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tb_exam"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_toolbar"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_navigation_back">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_zyus_logo" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/transparent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="#292E42"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:padding="20dp">

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                                    android:orientation="vertical">

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                                        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                                        android:text="1"
                                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                        android:textSize="13sp" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/tv_exam_name_exam"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                                        android:text="Text Exam"
                                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                        android:textSize="13sp" />

                                </LinearLayout>

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                    android:orientation="vertical">

                                    <LinearLayout
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                                        android:id="@+id/ln_suggestions_exam"
                                        android:background="@drawable/bg_call_a_friend_exam"
                                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                                        <ImageButton
                                            android:id="@+id/ib_call_friend_exam"
                                            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                                            android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
                                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_call_call_a_frnd_exam" />

                                        <ImageButton
                                            android:id="@+id/ib_fifty_fifty_exam"
                                            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                                            android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
                                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_fifty_fifty" />
                                    </LinearLayout>

                                    <LinearLayout
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                                        <TextView
                                            android:id="@+id/tv_hint_time_left_exam"
                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                                            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                                            android:text="Time Left :"
                                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                            android:textSize="13sp" />

                                        <TextView
                                            android:id="@+id/tv_timer_exam"
                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                                            android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
                                            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                                            android:text="00:00:02"
                                            android:textColor="#FF0137"
                                            android:textSize="13sp" />


                                    </LinearLayout>
                                </LinearLayout>

                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <View
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="0.3dp"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_question_name_exam"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                                android:minHeight="60dp"
                                android:text="Why is the speaker of portail important ?"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                android:textSize="13sp" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/iv_question_image_exam"
                                android:layout_width="70dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />


                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <com.tnm.zyus.custom.HeightWrappingViewPager
                                android:id="@+id/viewpager_exam"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                            <!--
                                                        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                                                            android:id="@+id/viewpager_exam"
                                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                            android:layout_height="300dp" />
                            -->

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tv_btn_first_exam"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                                    android:background="@drawable/btn_next_previous_exam"
                                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_arrow_double_left_exam"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                    android:text="First"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    android:textSize="11sp" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tv_btn_previous_exam"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                                    android:background="@drawable/btn_next_previous_exam"
                                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_arrow_left_exam"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                    android:text="Previous"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    android:textSize="11sp" />


                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tv_question_number_exam"
                                android:layout_width="30dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/btn_next_previous_exam"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                android:text="10"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                android:textSize="11sp" />



                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tv_btn_next_exam"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                                    android:background="@drawable/btn_next_previous_exam"
                                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_right_exam"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                    android:text="Next"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    android:textSize="11sp" />

                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/ln_take_brake_exam"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_margin="30dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/btn_start_exam"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tv_take_brake_exam"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                                    android:paddingStart="15dp"
                                    android:text="Take a Brake"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_coffee" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/btn_finish_exam"
                                android:layout_width="150dp"
                                android:layout_height="40dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_margin="30dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/btn_finish_exam"
                                android:text="Finish"
                                android:textAllCaps="false"
                                android:textColor="#0a870c"
                                android:visibility="gone" />

                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_loader_exam"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#F7F7F7"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What's possibly causing this and how to effectively resolve this ?

Here's the stacktrace as well:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tnm.zyus/com.tnm.zyus.activity.ExamActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #219: Error inflating class TextView
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2500)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:171)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5679)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #219: Error inflating class TextView
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                  at com.tnm.zyus.activity.ExamActivity.onCreate(ExamActivity.java:68)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5582)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2500) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:171) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5679) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
               Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_arrow_double_left_exam.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0800b2
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3439)
                  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
                  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1335)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:76)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:72)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createTextView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:176)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:101)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1035)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1092)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:690)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                  at com.tnm.zyus.activity.ExamActivity.onCreate(ExamActivity.java:68) 
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5582) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2500) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:171) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5679) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
               Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #2: invalid drawable tag vector
                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:986)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:930)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3435)
                  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602) 
                  at android.widget.TextView.<init>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if `@drawable/ic_arrow_double_left_exam` file exist or try to clean and rebuild.

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_arrow_double_left_exam.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0800b2
```