# getting a java.lang.NullPointerException: in a simple app

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i'm getting java.lang.NullPointerException. And i don't know how to solve it. looking for some help here
What i'v tried:

to look here [java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898444/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-start-activity-componentinfo)  But, it didn't help me

to clean and Rebuild project.
to Invalidate Cache and Restart in Android studio

and i'v discovered some problems in LayoutInflater.java
It cant resolve some imports"
[sorry cant import images yet this is and image of errors in LayoutInflater.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhKEK.jpg)

My XML file activity_main.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Team A" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="50sp"
                android:text="0" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/three_points_button_a"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:onClick="plusThreePointsA"
                android:text="+3 Points" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/two_points_button_a"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:onClick="plusTwoPointsA"
                android:text="+2 Points" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/free_throw_button_a"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:onClick="plusOnePointA"
                android:text="Free Throw" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <view
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Team B" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_b_score"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="50sp"
                android:text="0" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/three_points_button_b"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:onClick="plusThreePointsB"
                android:text="+3 Points" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/two_points_button_b"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:onClick="plusTwoPointsB"
                android:text="+2 Points" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/free_throw_button_b"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:onClick="plusOnePointB"
                android:text="Free Throw" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/reset_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="24dp"
            android:onClick="reset"
            android:text="Reset" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

My MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.problems;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int scoreA = 0;
    int scoreB = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void plusThreePointsA(View view){
        scoreA = scoreA+3;
        displayScoreA(scoreA);
    }

    public void plusTwoPointsA(View view){
        scoreA = scoreA+2;
        displayScoreA(scoreA);
    }

    public void plusOnePointA(View view){
        scoreA = scoreA+1;
        displayScoreA(scoreA);
    }

    public void plusThreePointsB(View view){
        scoreB = scoreB+3;
        displayScoreB(scoreB);
    }

    public void plusTwoPointsB(View view){
        scoreB = scoreB+2;
        displayScoreB(scoreB);
    }

    public void plusOnePointB(View view){
        scoreB = scoreB+1;
        displayScoreB(scoreB);
    }

    public void displayScoreA (int score){
        TextView viewScore = findViewById(R.id.team_a_score);
        viewScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));

    }
    public void displayScoreB (int score){
        TextView viewScore = findViewById(R.id.team_b_score);
        viewScore.setText(String.valueOf(score));

    }

    public void reset (View view){
        scoreA = 0;
        scoreB = 0;

        displayScoreA(scoreA);
        displayScoreB(scoreB);

    }
}
```

Error that i get

```
    --------- beginning of crash
05-11 08:14:25.720 4084-4084/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.problems, PID: 4084
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.problems/com.example.problems.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:715)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.example.problems.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
05-11 08:19:26.000 4084-4084/com.example.problems I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4084 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
<View android:layout_width="1dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
```

instead of :

```
<view
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            />
```

Comment: Oh my god... THX. so much trouble because of so little mistake...

Comment: Can you plz explain me, you found it just by looking in my xml file, or there is some clues in errors?

Comment: Actually i tried this code. somehow my android studio mentioned an error in xml file at line no 72 i guess. that's how i got it. Btw i am using android studio 3.5

Comment: I will try that version. Thx very much!

Comment: You can find mistake visually by looking at it, You were using `view` Instead of `View`. `View` is an parent for all view components like button, list, textview, radiobutton etc but `view` is not